# Pulling rows from HTML table into a list in Python then inserting rows into SQL table

Tags: python, html, sql

I have a HTML site that has a table that pulls up information for a user to edit. The issue am running into is when I try and insert the rows of this HTML table back to a SQL table.  I got as far as inserting records to the SQL table but it is inserting 5 rows instead of the 4 it should in my test data. It also will take the first row in the HTML table and inserts the same values 5 times instead of each row's different values. Am pretty sure am doing the for loops wrong but have been stuck for awhile trying to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<body>
        <h1>Edit Form</h1>
        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <form action="/submit" method="post">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>BOL No</th>
                            <th>Qty</th>
                            <th>Heat</th>
                            <th>ITEM DESC</th>
                            <th>WEIGHT</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for row in data %}
                        <tr>
                             <td><input type="text" name="BOLno" value="{{ BOLno }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="number" name="SERLTQTY" value="{{ row.SERLTQTY }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="SERLTNUM" value="{{ row.SERLTNUM }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="ITEMDESC" value="{{ row.ITEMDESC }}"></td>
                            <td><input type="number" name="WEIGHT" value="{{ row.WEIGHT }}"></td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Python:

```
@views.route('/edit/<bol>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def editbol(bol):
    sql_conn = odbc.connect('DRIVER=xxxxxxxxxxxxx;SERVER=xxxxxx;DATABASE=xxxxxxx;UID=xxxxxxx;PWD=xxxxxxx;')
    csr = sql_conn.cursor()
    BOLno = None
    SERLTQTY = None
    ITEMDESC = None
    WEIGHT = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        csr.execute(f"select * from BOL_VIEW where bolno = {bol}")
        data = csr.fetchall()
        return render_template('edit.html', data = data, BOLno = bol)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        formdata = []
        for x in request.form:
            BOLno = request.form['BOLno']
            SERLTQTY = request.form['SERLTQTY']
            SERLTNUM = request.form['SERLTNUM']
            ITEMDESC = request.form['ITEMDESC']
            WEIGHT = request.form['WEIGHT']
            formdata.append((BOLno, SERLTQTY, SERLTNUM, ITEMDESC, WEIGHT ))
        for line in formdata:
            csr.execute("INSERT INTO BOL_HIST_Rev2 (BOLno, SERLTQTY, SERLTNUM, ITEMDESC, WEIGHT) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (BOLno, SERLTQTY, SERLTNUM, ITEMDESC, WEIGHT))
            sql_conn.commit()
        csr.close()
        sql_conn.close()
        return f'<h1>{bol} insert</h1>'
    else:
        return f'<h1>{bol} end</h1>'
```

Comment: Why doesn't the `for x in request.form` loop use `x`? `request.form['BOLno']` is the same value each time through the loop. If you thought you were looping through the rows in the table, you're not.

Comment: You're looping through the keys of  the `request.form` dictionary. Since there are 5 inputs in the form, you'll insert 5 rows. And they'll be identical, containing the values from the last row of the form.

Comment: How would I modify it to loop through the rows instead?

Comment: You need to use `request.form.getlist('fieldname')` to get a list of all the inputs with that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `request.form.getlist()` to get a list of all the inputs with a particular name, then you can loop over these lists.

```
formdata = zip(request.form.getlist('BOLno'), request.form.getlist('SERLTQTY'), request.form.getlist('SERLTQTY'), request.form.getlist('ITEMDESC'), request.form.getlist('WEIGHT'))
csr.executemany("INSERT INTO BOL_HIST_Rev2 (BOLno, SERLTQTY, SERLTNUM, ITEMDESC, WEIGHT) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", formdata)
```

Notice that you can use `executemany()` to insert all the values at once, rather than looping over `formdata`.

Comment: That got me closer to where I need to be thank you. I am able to get a list with the correct values in them. Executemultiple doesn't seem to be an option for me to use. Do I need to import something extra to be able to use this. I did a search on this for pyodbc and didn't find anything.

Comment: I got it to work. I was not able to use executemultiple() but I was able to loop through the lines to insert.

Comment: Sorry, it's `executemany()`